# Provide visual feedback to user of application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making an app that contains a Qlistwidget. The user can double-click an entry in the list, or press the Enter key when an item has already been selected. When the user does either of those things, a function is run that does stuff, it doesn't really matter what.

I would like to provide visual feedback to the user that the expected action has indeed been carried out, but as simply as possible. Now, I'm not a UI/UX person, but the best way I can think of to intuitively show the user that the action has happened is to make the *item selection shadow* blink/flash.

I don't want to display a text message as that would take up space in the app and I'm specifically designing it to take up as little screen real-estate as possible.

Is this possible? If not, is there some other way I haven't thought of that would be just as good.

I'm using PyQt5 and developing on Windows.

I've looked through PyQt documentation and Googled it but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a QVariantAnimation that changes the color of the item:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.m_list_widget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.on_itemDoubleClicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.m_list_widget)

        for i in range(10):
            it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(f"Item-{i}")
            self.m_list_widget.addItem(it)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem)
    def on_itemDoubleClicked(self, it):
        self.m_list_widget.clearSelection()
        animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(self, duration=5 * 1000)
        animation.setProperty("item", it)

        color1 = QtGui.QColor("white")
        color2 = QtGui.QColor("red")

        colors = []
        number = 5

        color = color1 
        for _ in range(2*number+1):
            colors.append(color)
            color = color1 if color == color2 else color2

        numbers_of_colors = len(colors)
        for i, color in enumerate(colors):
            step = i / numbers_of_colors
            animation.setKeyValueAt(step, color)

        animation.valueChanged.connect(self.on_valueChanged)
        animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QVariant")
    def on_valueChanged(self, value):
        animation = self.sender()
        it = animation.property("item")
        if isinstance(value, QtGui.QColor):
            it.setBackground(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly, and I was easily able to edit it to appear more how I was imagining. I just haven't been able to get it working in my own code yet, but that is most likely due to my code not being the best. I will get it working eventually though :)